# Arithmetic Teichmüller curves, first eigenvalue of the Laplacian, McMullen's expander conjecture

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, geometric-group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$By a result due to Ellenberg and McReynolds, any finite index subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\Gamma(2) \subset \SL\left(2,\mathbb{Z}\right)$ is the Veech group of an arithmetic Teichmüller curve. Using these techniques, Matheus and Weitze-Schmithüsen construct explicit families of arithmetic Teichmüller curves, where a member of the family corresponds to a finite index subgroup $\Gamma(N) \subset \Gamma(2)$ and $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma(N)$ is a "cyclic" cover of $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma(2)$ made of $N$ copies of $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma(2)$ arranged in cyclic order. Ratner's estimates on mixing rate of the geodesic flow can be used to show that such a construction gives a sequence of arithmetic Teichmüller curves whose $\lambda_1$ tend to $0$.

If $\mathcal{O}$ generates an arithmetic Teichmüller curve, the $\SL\left(2,\mathbb{Z}\right)$-orbit of $\mathcal{O}$,  $\SL\left(2,\mathbb{Z}\right) \cdot \mathcal{O}$, can be viewed as a set of vertices in a graph whose edges connect a point $\mathcal{O}_i$ to $\mathcal{O}_j$ if there is a parabolic matrix in $\SL\left(2,\mathbb{Z}\right)$ [say, two parabolic generators are fixed] sending $\mathcal{O}_i$ to $\mathcal{O}_j$. A conjecture of McMullen posits that in the stratum $\mathcal{H}(2)$, the moduli space of flat surfaces with a single conical singularity of order $2$, the adjacency matrices of these graphs corresponding to Teichmüller curves have uniformly bounded spectral gap.

This seems to suggest that if one requires the Teichmüller curves to remain in a fixed stratum (at least $\mathcal{H}(2)$), one conjecturally cannot obtain sequences of Teichmüller curves whose $\lambda_1$ tend to $0$.

Question 1) Would the existence of a sequence of arithmetic Teichmüller curves in $\mathcal{H}(2)$ whose $\lambda_1$ tend to $0$ give a counter-example to McMullen's conjecture?

Question 2) Is there any reason to conjecture that sequences with $\lambda_1$ tending to $0$ can't exist for strata other than $\mathcal{H}(2)$? Why is $\mathcal{H}(2)$ special?